# How to generate X random numbers, where each number is between a range of A and B and the total sum of all number has to be Y

Tags: javascript, vb.net, math

I'm trying to code (JavaScript or VB.NET) an algorithm to generate x random numbers. Each random number has to be within a certain range and the total sum of all the numbers has to be equal to a constant. I don't particularly need the exact code (if I do, I can always ask when I start getting into debugging), but just the logic behind the whole thing.

In my particular case: I need to generate 4 random numbers, each between 0 and 10, and the total sum of the randomly generated numbers needs to be 24.

If you need any more information: please ask. Thanks in advance for trying to solve this with me .

**EDIT**: I should have added what I tried already (the code is in VB.NET but not that hard so ...)
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56753627/11511444) StackOverflow answer, this is what I tried already (it does not work though):

```
Dim intAverageNumberMark As Integer = 24 / 4
Dim intOverMark As Integer = 0
Dim intGeneratedRandomNumber As Integer = 0
Dim intCurrentSumOfRandomNumbers = 0
For intCounter = 0 To intNumberOfTowers - 1
    intGeneratedRandomNumber = RandomNumber(0 + intGeneratedRandomNumber, 10)
    intOverMark = If(intGeneratedRandomNumber > intAverageNumberMark, intGeneratedRandomNumber - intAverageNumberMark, 0)
    If intCounter = intNumberOfTowers - 1 Then
        intNumbers(intCounter) = 24 - intCurrentSumOfRandomNumbers
    End If
    intNumbers(intCounter) = intGeneratedRandomNumber
    intCurrentSumOfRandomNumbers += intGeneratedRandomNumber
    Debug.Print(intGeneratedRandomNumber)
Next
```

*`intNumbers()` is an array of declared with `Dim intNumbers(7) As Integer`.*

Comment: please add your try. what goes wrong?

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: had you have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50405397/split-number-into-4-random-numbers/50405632#50405632?

Comment: @NinaScholz, I've updated my post!

Comment: @user9938, I've updated my post!

Comment: Does each number have to be unique or can a number occur more than once?

Comment: @user9938, each number can occur multiple times .

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0;
loop
   generate new number
   if sum + new number <= constant{
    sum += new number
    break out of loop
   }
```

Comment: Following this, the code already stops at the fourth step since `0 + x`, where `x` is the random number between 0 and 10, is always 'lower or equal to' my constant 24...

Comment: My algorithm should be put into a loop on its own until you sum hits the exact value of the constant

Comment: Hi. Please use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71301723/edit) button to add explanations to your post. Comments are not the right place for extra information. In fact, comments tend to disappear without warning.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy approach is to take a brte force mthod and generate all possible combinations and take a random select of the this result set.

```js
function generate(from, to, size, sum) {
    function iter(right, delta) {
        if (delta < 0) return;
        if (!delta && right.length === size) return result.push(right);
        if (!delta || right.length === size) return;
        
        for (let i = from; i <= Math.min(delta, to); i++)
            iter([...right, i], delta - i);
    }
    
    const result = [];
    iter([], sum);
    return result;
}

const
    result = generate(0, 10, 4, 24);

console.log(result.length);
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += result.map(a => a.map(v => v.toString().padStart(2, ' ')).join(' ')).join('\n');
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're looking for is the algorithm, this is the approach I would take:

1. start out with your target total 'C'
2. Generate a random number 'r' in your desired range.
3. check if  r > C, if yes, reduce r to C
4. subtract r from C (updating C outside the loop)
5. repeat from 1 if C != 0

One thing I feel I should point out is that numbers will become increasingly non-random as C approaches 0 - the speed with which this occurs kind of depends on your random number upper and lower bounds compared to C.

You could also figure out a few extra data points about this algorithm, such as how many times the loop runs (how many numbers you generated).

Comment: Hey @johnydead83, thanks for your post! Do you have any idea how to adjust the algoritm to only generate exactly four numbers?